# How to setup touchegg with gnome on debian

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, touchpad

I am trying to setup touchegg on debian testing with gnome. I was able to compile and run it (without gui, daemon only). But unfortunately gestures doesn't work, though gnome two finger scroll works. Should I disable gnome gestures somehow to make touchegg work? How can I do it?

p.s. I have synaptic touchpad, my laptop is alienware 14, when I start touchegg it prints some gestures, so it looks like they should work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to make it work partially, unfortunately, only it was only able to recognize horizontal and vertical two-finger scroll. To achieve this, one should disable it's handling in synaptics driver:

```
synclient ClickFinger2=0 TapButton2=0 VertTwoFingerScroll=0 HorizTwoFingerScroll=0
```

Not sure why other gestures are not detected. My goal was to make multi finger gestures work, such as prev/next button in the browser, or switching to next/prev workspace. So I tried [xSwipe](https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe). Unfortunately, it doesn't work with the latest debian synaptics driver (some features it uses were removed from it). However, there is a forked version of this driver [here](https://github.com/felipejfc/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics), after removing xorg-input-synaptics package and installing the patched one, xSwipe starts working. I faced two problems with it:

1. It is not able to detect gnome for me, I just hard-coded it in the perl source file, but in fact this is not needed, cause it uses settings from 'other' section.
2. 'ctrl + alt + down' doesn't work for me, so I changed the shortcut to switch one workspace down to 'ctrl + alt + n' in gnome and updated xSwipe's config.

Hope somebody will find that usefull.

p.s. AFAIK, xSwipe is not able to detect pinch or rotate gestures, but I don't really need them. However, please let my know if somebody will find a way to make them work.